# How is ChatGPT able to perform part-of-speech tagging?

Tags: natural-language-processing, chatgpt

ChatGPT seems to be able of part-of-speech tagging:

[image]

[image]

How can its – possibly [emergent](https://www.jasonwei.net/blog/emergence) – ability to perform part-of-speech tagging be understood?

Comment: Is the answer 'because it inferred it from its training data' sufficient explanation? How it inferred it is a different question. But the 'why' is rather straight forward.

Comment: May as well ask how its emergent ability to write coherent English sentences can be understood!

Comment: @RobinvanHoorn: I changed the title of the question to be consistent with the question inside the post.